# Delay an entire repeating xml animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml

How can I delay a repeating animation in xml?

```
 <!-- wobbling animation -->
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="10"
    android:duration="50"
    android:repeatCount="5"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
```

This animation wobbles a view backwards and forwards rapidly. I would like to run it after a certain amount of time (say 1000 ms). **Adding a startOffset here delays each translation by the offset rather than the whole thing.** Is there an easy option to fix this behavior? I intend to put other animations in the xml too.

EDIT:
For clarity: Adding a start offset of 1000ms here results in an animation that waits 1000ms, slides right over 50ms, waits another 1000ms, slides back, waits again and so on. I want it to only wait once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use startOffset as it's the same animation. You can either break it to forward/reverse animations and offset the forward one (all XML) or use Handler in a code block as suggested.

Comment: That's a shame :D At least I know now!

Comment: Another thing you can do is to extend the `Animation` class and override `startOffset(long delay)` for reusability.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {

//sleep for x milliseconds
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() { 
          //do your stuff here
     } 
}, x);
```

}

here, anything that will happen by your onclick will occur after a pause of x milliseconds

Comment: Hi Hirak, I have bolded the bit that mentions how this does not produce the desired behaviour

Comment: ohh.. sry for not seeing that... but what u exactly mean by "startOffset here delays each translation by the offset rather than the whole thing"? i mean what do u mean by wholething?

Comment: Well the duration is set to 50ms, so this animation slides right over 50ms, then left over 50ms, and repeats. Adding a start offset of 1000ms results in an animation that waits 1000ms, slides right over 50ms, waits another 1000ms, slides back, waits again and so on. I want it to only wait once.

Comment: i have update my answer. hope it helps... now if u want to do UI changes during that sleep of x milliseconds, run thread on UI

Comment: Hmm thanks, I just would like to do this exclusively via xml if possible, particularly if I am combining this with other animations

Comment: then create 2 xml files. One from A to B with startOffset and no repeating. Another from B to A with repeating 4 times without startOffSet